# Split txt file with Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

How would I split a text file in thirds using the Terminal and if do not know exactly how many lines of text there are? I know it is around 3000 or so.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean splitting the total number of lines into three?

if yes, then write a small script that would do 
- count the number of lines. wc -l  should do that.
- divide the number by 3 and read the exact number of lines from the text file and write it to 3 buffers, for first two buffers write exact number of lines and write the rest of the lines to 3rd buffer/file since the total number of lines is not always proper multiple of 3. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't need it to be the proper multiple of 3 if a few of the files have one more line than the other I am fine with that. Sorry but also I am not so familiar with writing scripts in terminal I would just like to utilize the tools I already have than to go pay for a file splitter program. Thanks.